# Configuring ACL for kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a unsecured kafka instance with 2 brokers everything was running fine until I decided to configure ACL for topics, after ACL configuration my consumers stopped polling data from Kafka and I keep getting warning **Error while fetching metadata with correlation id** , my broker properties looks like below:-

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
```

And my client configuration looks like below:-

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
topic.name=topic-name
group.id=topic-group
```

I've used below command to configure ACL

```
bin\windows\kafka-acls.bat  --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:* Read --allow-host localhost  --consumer --topic topic-name --group topic-group
```

After having all above configuration when I start consumer it stopped receiving messages. Can someone point where I'm mistaking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be helpful if you'll put the full error and its stack trace...

Comment: The client start giving warning "Not authorized to access topic"

Comment: small note: shouldn't it be "localhost:2181/kafka"?

Comment: How about you post the full error message? See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Error+Handling+and+Logging

Comment: Is it possible to enable authorizer but without authentication?  I guess broker are not able to identify the session principal.(who they are).

Answer (score 0):

We are using ACLs successfully, but not with PLAINTEXT protocol. 
IMHO you shall use SSL protocol and instead of localhost use the real machine name.